# How to regex - pattern with literal asterisk

Tags: regex

I have 2 variants of strings:

1. some_prefix.**needed part***some_suffix
2. some_prefix.**needed part**

I need only '**needed part**' to be matched.

Left boundary is always *dot*.

Right boundary is *asterisk* (if exists) or end of line.

**Already tried:**

`/.*[.](.*)[*].*/`   - is working for first case

`/.*[.](.*)/`        - is working for second case

How to do the same with one regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/\.([^*]+)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DQ7rfD/2).

*Details*

- `\.` - a dot
- `([^*]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than a `*`.

You can also make sure you get the rightmost match by using `.*` before the pattern (as in the original regex):

```js
/.*\.([^*]+)/
```

Answer (score 1):

If supported, you might also use a lookbehind to assert a `.` to the left.

```
(?<=\.)[^*]+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=\.)` Positive lookbehind, assert `.` directly to the left
- `[^*]+` Match 1+ times any char except `*` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sXxclG/1)